# Run automatic tasks with quartz in springboot changing the intervals dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I'm new using Quartz with SpringBoot.

I want to send certain messages automaticaylly based on a time interval calculation.

For example if I have a list with 2 elements, I want to send the first element message at first, "hello" for example.

But then when I calculate the difference in time between the first element and the second one, let's say that between the first element "hello" message and the second message "how are you" are 21 minutes of difference, I will want to send the second message "how are you" when the 21 minutes has passed.

There is a way for doing something like this with Quartz and SpringBoot?.

Thank you so much guys!

For now I've only read the Quartz documentation and saw some examples, but I don't have yet clear how to do it.